# Javascript custom scrollbar

Tags: javascript, css

I am having the below code for display custom scrollbar. Here some background is showing, instead of this I need display a 1px thin line image.. How can I do this? I am using the TinyScroller

Css:

```
#wrapper_1 {width:99%; height:600px; padding:2px}
#scroll_1 {position:relative; width:99%; height:600px; overflow:auto}
#scrollcontent_1 {position:absolute; width:94%; z-index:200}
#scrollbar_1 {float:right; position:relative; border:0; display:none; width:15px; height:600px; z-index:100; background:url(images/scroll-bg.png)}
.scroller_1 {position:relative; top:0; cursor:pointer; border:0; width:15px; background-image:url(images/scroller.png); background-position:50% 50%; background-repeat:no-repeat}
.buttonclick_1 {}
```

Code:

```
<div id="wrapper_1">
<div id="scroll_1">
<div id="scrollcontent_1">
<h1>TinyScroller</h1>
<p>test message</p>
</div>
<div id="scrollbar_1">
<div id="scroller_1" class="scroller_1"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
TINY.scroller.init('scroll_1','scrollcontent_1','scrollbar_1','scroller_1','buttonclick_1');
</script>
```

Comment: Ummm.... What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using chrome, my friend..

Comment: Maybe will be usefull. I uses flexcroll module for custom scrolls. No problems with that and easy implementation. http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar

Comment: Webkit supports them natively: http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

Comment: actually this is working fine. But I need to know how to use a thin line come in the backside of the scroller box?

Comment: This above code is used to move the slider bar at the partially.. But I need this whole top to bottom of the slider bar..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you are in Chrome you can use plain ol' CSS:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 0 0 0 4px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 6px;
    min-height: 28px;
    padding: 100px 0 0;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1),inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    background: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    display: none;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/ysgBy/
Site to check out: http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

Comment: Yeah.. This is working. But I need a small background image must come back side of this color scroll box..

Comment: @user1587577 I am not sure what you mean, but you can edit the scrollbar in any way with CSS.

Comment: http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/complete_examples.html

Kindly check this link for my req.. Also this is 3rd coloumn with the title of "Fluid height container without mouse-wheel support"..

Please help me

Comment: I try this solution.. Its working in Chrome only.. But Now I am using all major browsers.. how can I use this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc
http://www.scriptiny.com/2009/09/javascript-scrollable-div/

I think your html is not correct. Try something like :

```
<div id="wrapper_1">

<div id="scroll_1">
    <div id="scrollcontent_1">
        <h1>TinyScroller</h1>
        <p>test message</p>
    </div>
    <div id="scrollbar_1">
        <div id="scroller"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```